# Yarn Client: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, apache-phoenix

I am trying to load some phoenix tables in memory. please help with the issue that I am facing below:

Spark submit Command Used:

```
 spark2-submit --name test \
 --master yarn \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Denv=dev" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/tmp/disruptor-3.3.6.jar:/tmp/phoenix-spark-4.14.1-HBase-1.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/APACHE_PHOENIX-4.14.0-cdh5.14.2.p0.3/lib/phoenix/phoenix-4.14.0-cdh5.14.2-client.jar"    \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/tmp/disruptor-3.3.6.jar:/tmp/phoenix-spark-4.14.1-HBase-1.2.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/APACHE_PHOENIX-4.14.0-cdh5.14.2.p0.3/lib/phoenix/phoenix-4.14.0-cdh5.14.2-client.jar"    \
--jars /tmp/dod-spark-jobs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   \
/tmp/dod-spark-jobs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am getting bellow mentioned error:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128) 
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod   (ObjectStreamClass.java:1475)
```

Please find below the pom file code :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudera.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
        <version>4.14.1-HBase-1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.14.0-cdh5.14.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
                <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1<version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1<version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>{main class...}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"></transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can not change the actual versions on phoenix or hbase the master.so I have tried to add that in the extrasclasspath.

if I give  spark.master=local, then the code is working fine. as soon as i try the yarn cluster it wont work.

Comment: This looks like runtime error. Did you import `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` in your source file?

Comment: hi All I have done little change in my spark submit command. Now the code is running in Yarn-client env but still not running in yarn-cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like there's a conflict between phoenix version you want use and the one spark is using.

Try shading : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661166/11968022

Answer (score 0):

We are using Phoenix version 4.7.x which can use both Spark 1.x and Spark 2 version. I had an issue when loading a phoenix driver during spark load.

The reason would be by default it uses the Spark 1.x library but we use Spark 2 library to load spark executors. Hence forced the phoenix engine to use Spark 2 library. Please note that the order of the configuration and jar is important even though it is a bit weird.

```
export conf1=" --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-spark2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-client.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/conf/"
export conf2=" --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-spark2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-client.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/conf/"
export jars="  --jars /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-spark2.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/phoenix/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292-client.jar"
```

This has resolved the class loader issue.